# jquery accordion menu with nested

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am facing now problem for nested accordion.

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/baUH8/  .. 1st level accordion is fine now i need 2nd level also. like

```
<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><img src="images/icon-2.png" />General Setting<i>Protocol Utilization</i></a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Widgets</span></a></li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Menus</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='#'><span>test 3rd</span></a></li>
          <li><a href='#'><span>test 3rd</span></a></li>
          <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>test 3rd</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

i want to add another accordion under **Menus** in html added but it not work. can you guys tell me how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check This Have a Same Function as you want

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sidebar ul li a').click(function(ev) {
        $('.sidebar .sub-menu').not($(this).parents('.sub-menu')).slideUp();
        $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
        ev.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/66kJs/4)

Your Code is Edited Here Please check it [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/baUH8/1/)

Comment: thanks this is work.. nicely... but for that i also need to change my code.. if i can not then i will do this way.. but have you idea .. how to do same thing on my code.. i just nested accordion

Comment: Now It Will Work Check New Link: In That General Setting -> Menu

Comment: @Alpesh nice compact code but clicking on `Firewall` is not working.. You might wanna fix it...

Comment: Dude i have added <ul class="sub-menu"> this class to ul inside ul so add this and it will work for all. study that carefully plz

Comment: @Alpesh.. thank u so much... u r great.. it work nicely.. cool man

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>***[Working result](http://jsfiddle.net/baUH8/2/embedded/result/)***</kbd>

Changed *click* selector to `$('#cssmenu a')`

Added a class to *inner ul* `<ul class='innerLevel'>`

Check if it is not a request to open *inner Menu slideUp* the prev open menu

```
if (!$(checkElement).hasClass('innerLevel')) {
    $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
}
```

*Not a perfect solution. Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.*

Hope it helps...

Comment: i have one more question. your code really work nice.. but i also now want to i keep active class when nested is open.. currently if nested open then other active class remove .

Comment: thank you so much ... great man.. but still can not figure out another thing.. it add active but when i click another accordion then active not remove from other one. so it mean if active one time then it not remove. before it was remove but it wasn't work nested accordion ... thank. i am trying .. if you can please can you see please

Comment: @pagol that's pretty complicated.. :-(

Comment: yes i think so.. as i am not so good on jquery it also more hard for me. my first code was ok.. that remove but not worked on nested.... ok let see if we can .. thanks again